# How to connect database with Mysql in php using phpstorm not PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code

```
<?php 
    try{
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '',$pdo_options);
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO minichat (pseudo, message)
VALUES(?, ?)');
        $req->execute(array($_POST['pseudo'], $_POST['message']));header('Location: minichat.php');
    }catch(Exception $e){
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: PHPStorm is an editor, though you can connect to a mysql database, it isn't done via code. PHPMyAdmin is just an interface to access the database.

Comment: How to configure phpstorm then

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/connecting-to-a-database.html